# Why Black Lives Matter? Why not Black's Lifes Matter?

Tags: verbs, nouns

We know Black Lives Matter.

But why it's said that way. Life and Lifes are nouns. Live and Lives are verbs.

It should be Blacks' Lives Matter. Or Black's Life Matters

Or well, I am confused.

Comment: @Stacky It refers to every individual's life, of course.

Comment: The plural of **life** is **lives**, a noun. **Lifes** isn't a word.

Comment: Many (but not all) nouns ending in 'f' or 'fe' are pluralised that way, for example knife, life, wife, calf, leaf.

Comment: @Stacky Perhaps you'd like to adjust ' "Black's Lives Matter" would work, too.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I think you must mean "Blacks' Lives Matter".

Comment: @TonyK I mean _"Black's Lives Matter"_ needs correcting, which I'm guessing is what you are implying I mean.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Ah, OK. Stacky deleted their comment, so I didn't pick up on that. I like "...which I'm guessing is what you are implying I mean" -- much recurse, very respect!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the phrase "Black Lives Matter", "black" isn't a noun. It's a poetic side-step by making "black" an adjective. It lends description to the type of life. What life? Black life. The plural of the noun life is "lives"; "lifes" is incorrect.

So to correct: What lives? Black lives.

Comment: Which lives????

Answer (score -1):

In “Black lives matter” the function of “Black” may not be immediately obvious.

NB **Of** = Associated with (the nature of the association is given by the context.)

In  “Black cats matter”, “black” would be an adjective.

In “Their lives matter”, “their” is an adjective (possessive).

In “Poor lives matter” we could understand this as either

(i) “{Lives that are poor(adj.)} matter” or

(ii) “The lives of {people who are poor(noun phrase)} matter.”

However, **black(adj.)** does not usually qualify “life/lives” in the meaning intended: ”He had a black life” / “His life was black” are marginally possible where “black” would mean “filled with evil deeds.”

But the intended meaning of “Black lives matter” is “{The lives of *(=associated with)* Black people} matter” and Black is an adjective used as a noun.

Thus

“{The lives associated with Black people} matter” or “Black people’s lives matter.” and hence: "Black lives matter."